# QBFC - Faulting module name: ucrtbase.DLL Exception code: 0xc0000409

Tags: qbfc

(I have solved this. Posting it in case someone else is having this issue.)

I have an application that integrates with Quickbooks using the QBFC13 library. It all works great when running the application from Visual Studio. However, after publishing and installing as a ClickOnce application, the app crashes when calling the SessionManager.OpenConnection method.

The following is the EventViewer entry: 
Faulting application name: ******.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x5c9bc8e2
Faulting module name: ucrtbase.dll, version: 10.0.17763.348, time stamp: 0x93e4fbe5
Exception code: 0xc0000409
Fault offset: 0x000a3652
Faulting process id: 0x47d4
Faulting application start time: 0x01d4e4dd895421ae
Faulting application path: C:\temp\test****.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbase.dll
Report Id: a081e5b3-502b-4591-9fc7-429d5658dba4
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turn off ClickOnce signing. Double click Properties. Then go to Signing tab and uncheck "Sign the ClickOnce Manifest".

I haven't figured out why this is a problem, but after switching it off and publishing again, the problem disappeared.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this a thousand times. You saved me! How on earth did you find this?

Comment: I had an older app that did work with ClickOnce and I compared each and every setting down the properties tabs until I got to the Signing tab. :)

Comment: I also had to go into my click once publish profile to turn it off there as well